# springBatch Itemwriter mysql to CSV with headers & inserting new line

Tags: mysql, csv, spring-batch

I want to write data to CSV file & have successfully written that but now I want to insert header & break line where ever needed.
Below is the code fro my itemWriter...

```
    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/examResult.txt" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">

        <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

            <property name="delimiter" value="|" />

            <property name="fieldExtractor">

                <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="studentName, percentage, dob" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: For header use http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setHeaderCallback-org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback-
About break-line I can't be helpful because I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: my current file is

name|percentage|date
Rita Paul|92.0|1993-02-01
Han Yenn|83.0|1965-02-01

now i want to insert new line after percentage through configuration. How to do it?